# Move a box from the bottom to the top right with CSS

Tags: css

I need help moving the box with the size selection and add to cart etc.. from the bottom to the top right, under the product title and short description.

The product page is at http://184.178.186.166/scarlet/trunk-lynyrd-skynyrd-tee-1571.html

I can't seem to find what css to edit.

This is the template file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     rwd_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2014 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
 * @see Mage_Review_Block_Product_View
 */
?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view">
    <div class="product-essential">
        <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
            <div class="no-display">
                <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
            </div>

            <div class="product-img-box">
                <div class="product-name">
                    <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
            </div>

            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="product-name">
                    <span class="h1"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></span>
                </div>

                <div class="price-info">
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
                </div>

                <div class="extra-info">
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'default', false)?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_availability'); ?>
                </div>

                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>

                <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                    <div class="short-description">
                        <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif;?>




                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>

                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                <?php endif;?>

            </div>

            <div class="add-to-cart-wrapper">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

                <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                    <div class="add-to-box">
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                            <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                    </div>

                <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <div class="add-to-box">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>

            <div class="clearer"></div>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
            productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    var form = this.form;
                    var oldUrl = form.action;

                    if (url) {
                       form.action = url;
                    }
                    var e = null;
                    try {
                        this.form.submit();
                    } catch (e) {
                    }
                    this.form.action = oldUrl;
                    if (e) {
                        throw e;
                    }

                    if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                        button.disabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

            productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
                if(this.validator) {
                    var nv = Validation.methods;
                    delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                    delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                    delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                    // Remove custom datetime validators
                    for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                        if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                            delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                        }
                    }

                    if (this.validator.validate()) {
                        if (url) {
                            this.form.action = url;
                        }
                        this.form.submit();
                    }
                    Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
                }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
        //]]>
        </script>
    </div>

    <div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
        <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
            <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
                <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                    <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                    <dd class="tab-container">
                        <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Opened for me. Can you try again?

Comment: Service Temporarily Unavailable - not opening.

Comment: Sorry, had it limited to my ip. Forgot.

Comment: Your html looks messed up.

Comment: Can you let me know where and how?

Comment: I added the html from the template file.

Comment: You probably messed up something accidentally when changing the theme code. I suggest you install the theme again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need both CSS and template changes. "Description" and "Additional info" are outside the div that contains the image and short description.

A quick fix might be these changes:

```
    .product-options {
      width: 49%;
      margin: 0px 10px 0;
      padding: 10px 15px 15px;
      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
      /* clear: both; REMOVED */
      position: relative;
      float: right;  /*edited : new */
    }

    .product-view .add-to-cart:after {
      clear: none !important;
    }

    .product-view .add-to-cart {
      border-bottom: 0px solid #cccccc;
    }
    .product-view .add-to-links {
      clear: none;
      margin-top: 10px;
      float: right;
      margin-right: 0px;
    }

    .product-view .sharing-links {
      float: right;
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-right: 10px;
    }
   .product-shop {
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-right: 10px;
   }
```

then you can get it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: A lot closer! I updated it. How do you think we can move the add to cart to under the compare?

Comment: Well thanks for getting me closer anyway. I marked it answered.